# Convert Dynamic Type to List

Tags: c#, wpf, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the Facebook C# SDK to get data. I want to use `parallel.foreach` but cannot use it - instead, an error occurs:

> Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type

So is there any way I can convert data retrieved to a list?

```
dynamic friends = app.Get("me/friends");   
Parallel.ForEach(friends.data, friendsData =>
    {
        Interlocked.Increment(ref infoCount);
        LoadFriends(friend, infoCount);
    });
```

Comment: What kind of data is coming back in friends? Is it XML, a data structure, what?  And does using var instead of dynamic solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't use a lambda expression, have you tried an anonymous method?

```
dynamic friends = app.Get("me/friends");   
    Parallel.ForEach(friends.data, delegate(dynamic friendsData)
       {
           Interlocked.Increment(ref infoCount);
           LoadFriends(friend, infoCount);

       });
```

Comment: Try converting friends.data to IEnumerable before calling Parallel.ForEach

Answer (score 1):

I used the following code to convert the JsonArray to a Dictionary of id as a key and names as value

```
var friendlist = (friends.data as Facebook.JsonArray).ToDictionary( 
                p => (p as Facebook.JsonObject)["id"].ToString(), 
                p => (p as Facebook.JsonObject)["name"].ToString());

Parallel.ForEach(friendlist, friend
       {
           Interlocked.Increment(ref infoCount);
           LoadFriends(friend, infoCount);
       }
```