# how to convert dynamic to list<dynamic>

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic

i have a variable swimlaneAttribute:

```
List<dynamic> swimlaneAttributes = new List<dynamic>();
```

but in a function i have a return type of dynamic

```
public dynamic GetSwimlaneAttribute(List<ProjectSwimlaneAttribute> swimlaneAttributeTable, Dictionary<string, string> dic)
    {
        dynamic swimlaneAttributes = null;

        swimlaneAttributes = swimlaneAttributeTable.Select(s => new
        {
            ID = s.Id,
            DataType = s.AttributeDataType,
            IsCriticalField = s.IsCriticalField,
        });
        return swimlaneAttributes;
    }
```

this will return some records from table parameter that i am passing!!

now i have to call this  `GetSwimlaneAttribute` function, in return i will get all the required records(from a table)
but when i pass this to `swimlaneAttributes` it goes to catch block!!!

```
swimlaneAttributes = GetSwimlaneAttribute();
```

if i pass it this way, (i think the record count becomes 0)

```
//swimalneAttributes = GetSwimlaneAttribute as List<dynamic>;
```

So how to convert **Dynamic** to **List**

Thanks!

Comment: public List<dynamic> GetSwimlaneAttribute() ??

Comment: @user3905379 Possible : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409894/convert-dynamic-type-to-list

Comment: So what's the actual type of the object returned by `GetSwimlaneAttribute()`? It doesn't help that you've talked about it "going to catch blcok" but without saying anything about what the error is... basically you need to give us more information.

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry,
error is like this:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: That sounds like a *compile-time* error, not an exception. And you still haven't told us what the actual type of the object returned by the method is. Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @nikita i need to provide data to other functions where they are present in **dynamic** form, and i can't change that!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're currently returning a sequence of anonymous type objects. That sequence can't be cast to a `List<T>` because it *isn't* a `List<T>`.

You could change the declaration to:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> GetSwimlaneAttribute(...)
```

with no change to the body of the code - then to get a `List<dynamic>` just call it as:

```
List<dynamic> list = GetSwimlaneAttribute(...).ToList();
```

If you absolutely can't change the declaration, you could convert it outside the method:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> sequence = GetSwimlaneAttribute(...);
List<dynamic> list = sequence.ToList();
```

Or call the extension method directly:

```
List<dynamic> list = Enumerable.ToList<dynamic>(GetSwimlaneAttirbute(...));
```

However, you should be aware that anonymous types don't cross assembly boundaries (without a bit of hackery). You should strongly consider creating a *named* type for this instead.

Additionally, your method body is a bit crufty - you declare a variable and assign it a null value, then immediately assign a different value, and then just return that value. The whole thing could be written as:

```
return swimlaneAttributeTable.Select(s => new
{
    ID = s.Id,
    DataType = s.AttributeDataType,
    IsCriticalField = s.IsCriticalField,
});
```

Comment: thank you very much will try!!
also for that Method body!!
thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
  List<dynamic> lstDynamic = new List<dynamic>();
  lstDynamic.Add(GetSwimlaneAttribute());
```

and use lstDynamic.

Comment: thanks man,
i tried it, but no luck!!

it returned with zero lists, (that means without any record)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you try this way?

```
public List<dynamic> GetSwimlaneAttribute(List<ProjectSwimlaneAttribute> swimlaneAttributeTable, Dictionary<string, string> dic)
{
    List<dynamic> swimlaneAttributes = new List<dynamic>(); // modified dynamic to List<dynamic>

    swimlaneAttributes = swimlaneAttributeTable.Select(s => new
    {
        ID = s.Id,
        DataType = s.AttributeDataType,
        IsCriticalField = s.IsCriticalField,
    });
    return swimlaneAttributes;
}
```

Comment: i thought of that, but i since this function will be called by other functions which are defined in **dynamic** way, i need to return to them,
and i cant change those part of code!!!

Thanks for your Help!!